# Unity iOS 64 bit build crash at com.apple.IOAccelerator.BlockFences, Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash, il2cpp

I am using Unity 4.6.6f2 and made il2cpp build to support 64 bit requirement from apple. I am having strange random crash and in device crash logs, I see these crash reports. It is happening on multiple devices and all of them have this in common:
Here's the logs:

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-18 12:06:11.292 +0400
Launch Time:         2015-06-18 11:50:59.940 +0400
OS Version:          iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000029c
Triggered by Thread:  36

Thread 36 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.IOAccelerator.BlockFences
Thread 36 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194b739f4 objc_disposeClassPair + 192
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194b739bc objc_disposeClassPair + 136
2   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x000000019520190c _Block_release + 252
3   IOAccelerator                   0x000000018d68aca4 ioAccelCommandQueueBlockFenceCallback + 60
4   IOKit                           0x00000001851c58cc IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
5   IOKit                           0x00000001851c596c _IODispatchCalloutWithDispatch + 36
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951b2a2c dispatch_mig_server + 432
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951ad368 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951c20c4 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 788
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951af4d0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 284
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951b72a0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 672
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951b0470 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951b9220 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 660
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001951ba758 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001953892e0 _pthread_wqthread + 812
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000195388fa4 start_wqthread + 0
```

Comment: I have the same issue with 5.1.2f1.

Comment: try Graphics API to Open GL ES 2.0, it worked for me.

Comment: Did disabling Metal fix issue for you?

Comment: ps more discussion (apparently started by the same OP) on the [unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ios-64-bit-build-crash-at-com-apple-ioaccelerator-blockfences-exception-subtype-kern_invalid.334427/), although it's still unresolved. people are suggesting it has to do with the Everyplay plugin for unity there